# Matching entire string in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Consider the following string:

```
string = "I have #1 file and #11 folders"
```

I would like to replace the pattern `#1` with the word `one`, but I don't want to modify th `#11`. The result should be:

```
string = "I have one file and #11 folders"
```

I have tried:

```
 string = gsub("#1", "one, string, fixed = TRUE)
```

but this replaces both #1 and #11. I have also tried:

```
 string = gsub("^#1$", "one, string, fixed = TRUE)
```

but this doesn't replace anything since the pattern is part of a string that contains spaces.

Please note that if the initial string looked like:

```
string = "I have #1 file blah blah blah and #11 folders"
```

I would want the result to be:

```
string = "I have 1 file blah blah blah and #11 folders"
```

In other words, I literally just want to change the exact pattern `#1` without touching the rest of the string. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `perl=TRUE` argument to tools like `gsub` then the perl regex engine will be used which has some options that could help.

The pattern "#1\\b" will match #1 followed by a word boundary, so it would match #1, but not #11 (since there is no boundary between the 2 1's).  There are also tools for positive and negative look ahead which look for things following your pattern (like the word file maybe), but does not include them in the part to be replaced.

Comment: That sounds like the same as using the `[:alpha:]` class in the `pattern` argument, without the `perl = TRUE`, yes?

Comment: @Codoremifa, `\w` is similar to `[:alpha:]`, but what I meant (and have now fixed) is `\b` (both need an extra `\` to escape the other) which matches the nothing between a "word" character and a "nonword" character, in this case the nothing between "1" and " " will match, but not the one between "1" and "1".

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood right, but does this help -

```
a <- "I have #1 file and #11 folders"
b <- "I have #1file and #11 folders"
c <- "I have #1,file and #11 folders"

> gsub(x = a, pattern = "#1.*file", replacement = "one file")
[1] "I have one file and #11 folders"
> gsub(x = b, pattern = "#1.*file", replacement = "one file")
[1] "I have one file and #11 folders"
> gsub(x = c, pattern = "#1.*file", replacement = "one file")
[1] "I have one file and #11 folders"
```

Comment: Could you please explain the role of .* ? Thanks

Comment: The `.*` says look for any number of characters between "#1" and "file". This grep would change the string, "I have #1 blah blah blah file", also to "I have one file".

Comment: Oh I understand now. So what if I don't know what is the word that comes after `#1` (i.e. I don't know if the word is `file` or something else)? Is there a way of generalizing this? And also, if the string was "I have #1 blah blah file", I would want to keep the blah blah

Comment: Can you list out multiple such cases and the expected output for those cases? I'm not sure i understand the exact problem.

Comment: It's the same `gsub` statment that's being run on `a,b, and c`. You can try passing the new string to it, it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly for the string : "I have #1 file blah blah blah and #11 folders" as I mentioned above

Comment: Is this not what you want? (your example on the question says 1 and not one btw) `d<-"I have #1 file blah blah blah and #11 folders";
gsub(x = d, pattern = "#1.*file", replacement = "one file");
[1] "I have one file blah blah blah and #11 folders"`

Comment: Yes that works great, you are right, sorry. Thanks a lot for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the space after #1 to your advantage:

```
gsub("#1 ", "one ", string, fixed = TRUE)

[1] "I have one file and #11 folders"
```

Comment: This would fail for the phrase "I have #1 file and #1 folder".

Comment: I should have specified in my post that this is a very simplistic example. In reality, I am matching the pattern in a file, where I don't know how many spaces precede or come after the pattern. Therefore, this solution doesn't really work for me.

Comment: Justin no it won't...? @Mariam - this solution works for all of your examples.

Comment: @Stu since I don't know how many spaces are before and after `#1` in my real life example, this solution won't work. In other words, if I have 10 spaces before, and 3 after, this won't work. The problem is that I am not aware of how many spaces there are.

Comment: @Mariam nonsense - try it.

Comment: OP was having problems gsub'ing #1 because that was hitting the #11 as well, but OP did want to replace all the #1's

Comment: ok, regardless, OP is dead wrong that this answer doesn't work for them (or if it doesn't it's not for the reasons they listed)

Comment: Okay, cleaning up the comments.

Comment: @Arun agreed. The only circumstance when this does something else is if there is punctuation after the #1, which is unspecified in OP and unlikely given the examples.